# Why isn't Facebook's Open Graph debugger picking up the og:image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sample URL: https://www.sunriseclick.com/referandwinbig/KP49SW66XL

I have an og:image specified like so:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sunriseclick.com/img/promo/referral-2015/FB-referral-set-3.jpg">
```

But looking at [FB's Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) it says the image could not be downloaded (unlikely as the file path is correct) or is too small (untrue; the image is at FB's recommended size of 1200x630).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you scrape the image URL `http://www.sunriseclick.com/img/promo/referral-2015/FB-referral-set-3.jpg` itself, you get errors “Could not retrieve data from URL.” and “Warning Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 9999 milliseconds with 280004 out of 524288 bytes received”

Comment: What are you using to scrape it? I just tried running `curl` on that link and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I’m talking about the debug tool. That uses the same methodology in the background, that Facebook uses to read any kind of external content. And if that tool says it can not read your image, then that’s where your problem lies. So you need to go investigate what might cause this timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by reducing the file size of the image to ensure Facebook's crawler could load it quickly enough.